# Which assembly does a ViewModel belong to?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm just learning the ropes of the MVVM pattern in WPF applications, and I can imagine that this sounds like an incredibly stupid question, but here goes anyway:

I already have a model in one assembly, which is a simple class library. In a different assembly, I've created a simple view in xaml. Now the books all tell the same: link them together with a viewmodel. My question is though, where does this viewmodel belong:

- Is it more or less part of the view, and should it be in that assembly?
- Is the viewmodel meant to be universal, so it belongs together with the model assembly?
- Does the viewmodel get its own assembly?

I know the MVVM pattern is merely a design guideline and not a strict set of rules, but I feel it's better to learn things the right way.

**EDIT**

Follow-up question: is a viewmodel meant to be re-usable? I can imagine a scenario where it would be usefull if you could use the same viewmodel for a WPF desktop application and a silverlight web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It facilitates building the view, so it belongs in the view assembly.

Think of it like this: could you take your model assembly and use it in a different style of application, e.g. a Windows service or a web application? Is there anything that is irrelevant to that style of application in that assembly? If the answers are yes and no, you've built yourself a useful re-usable component that is independent of the type of user interface.

Comment: Could you tell me how this mindset fits in my follow-up question?

Comment: ViewModels tend to be tied quite tightly to the UI in question. You may want to reuse them for a Silverlight application but, certainly beyond that, they would be a bit useless. While putting your models in a different assembly shows a good separation of concerns, I'd say view models are part of the same concern (the UI) and putting them on their own is likely overkill unless you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the project, I put the ViewModels either in the same assembly as the views, or in their own assembly, but never in the model assembly. The model shouldn't contain anything related to the UI.